# Problems trying to 'tail' latest log files

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I was wondering if someone can help me out - working on a bit of a problem and I seem to be getting nowhere. Ye olde Google isn't throwing up much either..

Basically I have a variety of server log files (server.log, full.log to name a few) and they're all buried and archived into directories in /logs, eg: 26_03_2012_11-17 & 26_03_2012_09-17. The script I'm trying to create would ideally work with 'tail.sh problems' and it would find the most recent problems.log file and 'tail -f' it. Unfortunately I've been struggling, trying to figure out how to tail -f the most recent server.log, problems.log etc.

What I have at the moment works (I think) when you are in one of those date directories, I just need it to search recursively to find the most recent version of that file.

```
tail -f `ls -tr | grep full.log | tail`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: like this, it's quite hard to help. Give more info with the directory structure in case it is not /var/log all logs and some bits of code where you thing the problem is...

Comment: Yeah, problem I have is that what I have at the moment is pretty messy. Also, it's something I'm using at work and I don't want to accidentally share too much info with the world, even though there's nothing that useful in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
tail -f $( ls -1tr `find /my/root/log/dir -name "*.log"` | tail -1 )
```

This does `tail -f` on the most recent log file.  If you want tail -f on the most recent `server.log`:

```
tail -f $( ls -1tr `find /my/root/log/dir -name "server.log"` | tail -1 )
```

Comment: This works great, thanks.

Now I just need to figure out how to clean up what I currently have and get it to work within a certain path, eg:

app1 (/apps/app1): #tail server - to 'tail -f' server.log in /apps/app1/logs/26_03_2012_11-17/server.log

and

app2 (/apps/app2): #tail server - to 'tail -f' server.log in /apps/app2/logs/26_03_2012_11-17/server.log